# bootstrap twitter 3 natural language forms

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying do forms like http://goodui.org/#48 in bootstrap twitter 3.

And on full width is looks good:
[image: wide row]
[img 1]

But when i change the size to lower i get:
[image: narrow row]

[img 2]

It is changing in that way because of `class="form-control"`, but when i remove this class i also remove how field looks.

My code:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form class="form-inline" role="search">
            Chcę

            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Wynająć</option>
                    <option>Kupić</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Mieszkanie</option>
                    <option>Pokój</option>
                    <option>Dom</option>
                    <option>Lokal użykowy</option>
                    <option>Hala / Magazyn</option>
                    <option>Inne</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            w

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Lokalizacja" value="Polska, Poznań">
            </div>

            i płacić od

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="od" style="max-width:60px;">
            </div>

            do

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="do" style="max-width:60px;">
            </div>

            miesięcznie + rachunki.
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to write code in bootstrap twitter 3 to show form like on [img 1] when the size of window is narrow.
 I don't want this fields to resize and move to others row.

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15541 - issue on github